# How to list projects associated with Google Apps triggers?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

Under All Triggers, I can see all the Google Apps triggers that exist for my user, but I cannot see what project they are associated with. How can I find the project associated with each Google Apps trigger?

Comment: It is *not* possible to use one script project to access information about triggers in another script project.  It *is* possible to get the file ID of the document that a script is associated with using code, but **ONLY** for *that* script.  Again, you can not write some code in one project, to get information about triggers in other script projects.  That's not possible. 
 And there is no built-in way to display what trigger is associates with what document file, or script file.

Comment: Thanks, I feared that might be the case. If you create a function with the same name in multiple Google spreadsheet apps scripts with each function called by its own trigger, then it seems like the only way to distinguish them is to go through every spreadsheet. It's a major design flaw IMHO.

Comment: It is a big problem.  You can visit the issue tracker to determine if someone has already posted a feature request, and if not, make your own.  [Apps Script Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open)

Comment: Thanks I will do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mcarans,

Facing that problem i've found a (dirty) workaround. Please continue reading if you are really desperate and has a strong stomach.

- Using Chrome open any script (where you can access to *Edit >> All your triggers* menu)
- Open the Chrome developers tools (Ctrl+Shift+j)
- Go to Network tab
- Go to *Edit >> All your triggers*
- Copy the recorded *triggersService* XHR Response
- Paste it in any txt editor and dive in for triggers names and **document keys** !!!
- Use the keys to locate de documents.

After that, keep a log with your installed triggers!

Comment: Marking as accepted answer. I wish there were something simpler but this is a good workaround. Thanks a lot!